# Ionic PWA deploy

Tags: heroku, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to deploy a Progressive Web App version of my Ionic 2 project to Heroku but it doesn't seem to work.  What I'm trying is to use "Ionic build browser --prod" and then deploy the www folder, but I'm not getting any response from Heroku (Seems that nothing has being deployed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps you are supposed to take:

1. `Ionic build browser --prod` - creates the main.js file to be deployed
2. Go to .gitignore file and remove the mentions of www/ so git picks it up and add these two lines so platforms browsers folder is picked up

   ```
   platforms/*
   !platforms/browser/
   !platforms/browser/www
   !platforms/browser/www/plugins
   ```
3. Add these 2 libraries to your package.json (don't forget to run npm install)

   ```
   "connect": "^3.5.0",
   "serve-static": "^1.11.1"
   ```
4. Add a start to your npm scripts in package.json

   ```
   "start": "node server.js"
   ```
5. Add server.js to your project folder with the following code:

   ```
   var connect = require('connect'),
   serveStatic = require('serve-static');

   var app = connect();

   app.use(serveStatic("platforms/browser/www"))
   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
   ```

   Please note this code is only for ionic apps and not normal angular apps.
   At this point you can write `npm start` or `node server.js` in your cmd and you can test to see how it will run.
6. Commit your code to heroku git using `git push heroku master`. Please note to have the heroku git on your remote list. You may do `git remote -v` to check if thats the case. If not get the url from the website and add it.
7. Optional - Put the www/ folder back in .gitignore and `git rm --cached -r ./www` to delete them from your git. This is so your co workers wont have merge conflicts on your main.js everytime you commit. The same for platforms/browser.

You are supposed to see heroku installing and deployed a node application in your enviornment after pushing to their git

**NOTE** If you are using Heroku you could probably do this with Heroku builds rather than playing with your git. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds

Comment: Do these steps are  made in the `\platforms\browser` folder or the main project folder?

Comment: Main project folder

Comment: Cordova plugins doesn't work on the pwa deployed like you said. Can i fix that or it really can't work? Also, when a update the html and deploy changes to heroku, none of changes made to the app apears.

Comment: Well I edited my answer to include platforms/browser/www instead of www/main.js. I tested on my app and it loaded the plugins

Answer (score 0):

An update, as i ran the same task today:

It may be preferable to avoid

- Adding and maintaining "server" code along with your app.
- Pushing the built app (`www/`) in your version control system.

You can rely just on the heroku buildpacks. To do that you would need two buildpacks:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git

Your app will be detected first as node app and will build, and later as a static site and served.

#### First, build the app up on heroku, don't add www to your version control system:

The first buildpack will detect your app as node app, and run the build after the postbuild script.

you need to add this line to you `package.json` scripts:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "ionic build --prod"
```

and add the ionic cli to your dev-dependencies so it can be available for heroku on the build process

```
npm install ionic --save-dev
```

#### Second, serve the static files generated:

The second buildpack will serve the static files generated in `www`. For that you need to tell the buildpack how to serve the files with a `static.json` file: *(this one is somewhat equivalent to the config for firebase in the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/progressive-web-app))*

`/static.json`:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "headers": {
    "ngsw-worker.js": {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    "/build/app/**": {
      "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=31536000"
    }
  },
  "root": "www/"
}
```

Looks like the new Ionic doesn't generate the `'www/build/app/...'` directory anymore, just added to be consistent with the above mentioned docs.

Just those two changes, along with the buildpacks are enough to run the PWA on heroku / dokku